# Facing errors while running and NPM script

Tags: javascript, json

When I try to run the script, the CLI returns some weird error I am not able to understand. Can someone explain what has happened? TIA.
[CLI error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxmd0.png)

[image: file directory]

Answer (score 0):

your webpack output path is wrong, use

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js"), "index.js"),

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "js/bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
}
```

Comment: `const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
 entry: "./src/js/index.js",
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  filename: "js/bundle.js"
 },
 devServer: {
  contentBase: "./dist"
 }
}` The code is correct i guess, even the path is set to /dist

Comment: output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/dist'), ..}

Comment: sorry, does not work.... i added my file directory for further clarification though

Comment: no, does not work either; what additional information should i put?